# nginx: auth_basic for everything except a specific location

Tags: nginx

How can I enable HTTP Basic Auth for everything *except* for a certain file?

Here is my current server block configuration for the location:

```
location / {
       auth_basic "The password, you must enter.";
       auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
}

location /README {
       auth_basic off;
}
```

However, on `/README`, it is still prompting for a password.

How can we fix this?

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: I dont see any error in your config.
Here is a detailed answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/330580/enable-basic-auth-sitewide-and-disabling-it-for-subpages

Answer (score 43):

Try to use sign = , that helps you:

```
location = /README {
       auth_basic off;
       allow all; # Allow all to see content 
}
```

Comment: is `allow all` really necessary? Is that not default behaviour?

Comment: It’s not necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I am doing something similar using "map" instead of "if" to assign the auth_basic realm variable and htpasswd file:

```
map $http_host $siteenv {
  default       dev;

  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.dev dev;
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.devprofile devprofile;
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.devdebug devdebug;
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.test test;
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.demo demo;
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.stage stage;

  # Live
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.live live;
  ~^.*\.(?P<subdomain>.+)\.[a-zA-Z]* live;
}

map $http_host $auth_type {
  default       "Restricted";

  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.dev "Development";
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.devprofile "Development";
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.devdebug "Development";
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.test "Testing";
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.stage "Stage";
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.demo "Demo";

  # Live
  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.live "off";
  ~^.*\.(?P<subdomain>.+)\.[a-zA-Z]* "off";
}

server {
  .. etc ..

  auth_basic            $auth_type;
  auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/conf.d/htpasswd-$siteenv;
}
```

Comment: Although not being most voted, I believe this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the following:

```
location = /hc.php {
  auth_basic "off";
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

- The narrow match:`location = /somefile.txt {}` comes first, so `location / {}` can capture the remaining requests
- `auth_basic "off"` requires the quotes around it as far as I know
- I also use the exact (full, if you like) match, in order to stop iteration over the other locations defined in the config (read below quote for more info on what it does)

Probably this would work in different orders, and/or without the double quotes also, but why not try to do things as correct and complete as possible, if possible.

> The most important modifiers are:
>
> **(none)** No modifier at all means that the location is interpreted as a prefix. To determine a match, the location will now be matched against the beginning of the URI.
>
> **=**: The equal sign can be used if the location needs to match the exact request URI. When this modifier is matched, the search stops right here.
>
> **~**: Tilde means that this location will be interpreted as a case-sensitive RE match.
>
> **~***: Tilde followed by an asterisk modifier means that the location will be processed as a case-insensitive RE match.
>
> **^~**: Assuming this block is the best non-RE match, a carat followed by a tilde modifier means that RE matching will not take place.

quoted from here: https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive

Answer (score 0):

Only auth_basic off didn't work for me
If we have to skip auth for ALL uri's under our url

```
location ^~ /some/location/to_skip/ {
  auth_basic off;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `auth_basic off;` works for generally simple pages with no reference to any other things that could be linked to the page. So here's the trick:

Actually when you set `auth_basic off;` for certain uri, you need to be sure there is no reference for any brother-uris!!! But what if it is?

Well, I found no better way then just to track it. By default you need to check `/var/log/nginx/access.log` for all 401 (unauthorized) statuses once you did a request to the `/desired-url` which you want to put under `location` wit `auth_basic off;` directive.

So what was interesting in `access.log`? I noticed that once i trigger /desired-url I immediately got reference for `/static/` files. What I did?

Simply created new `location` directive for `/static/` path and of course it includes `auth_basic off;` directive.

Not only one static folder, there was also 401 status for `/favicon` file and some other files and folders.

So for all of them I simply created new `location` blocks with `auth_basic off;` directive.
Be aware creating `location` for new path may not resolve the issue as new path could be following after. So constantly track access.log

I know it looks like a raw/fast solution and definitely can be improved/optimized but so there was nothing on the web that helped me better so here I share my experience.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you. In my case i had to do something like: 

`location ~* /noauthdirection {
    auth_basic "off";
    include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
}

location /static {
    auth_basic "off";
    include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
}`