# Why ignores nginx my "auth_basic off" for sub-path location directive?

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication, nginx-location, static-content

Nginx ([docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), `1.17.2`) requires a basic authentication for a subpath. Although my config says otherwise for `https://example.org/subpath`:

```
//  /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysetup.conf

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.org;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    access_log /var/logs/nginx/example.org.access.log;
    error_log /var/logs/nginx/example.org.error.log info;

    root /var/www/domains/example.org/stage_root/;        

    location / {
        auth_basic "example.org server";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/htaccess/htaccess_example.org;
    }
    location /subpath {
        auth_basic off;
        root /var/www/domains/example.org/;
    }
}
```

**Some Facts:**

- nignx accepts my conf without warnings
- There are more domains served (all in similar `server` directives) and an upstream plex.
- the docker image is part of `docker-compose` setup with its own network (nginx is the gate)
- The correct content is served: `/var/www/domains/example.org/subpath/`
- Commenting-out the global `auth_basic` disables the auth request

**What I've tried so far:**

- Moving the auth_basic setup from the `location /` block up to the `server` block.
- `off` with double-quotes ([suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/566702), although not required in the [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/))
- searched for invalid chars/whitespaces
- removing the complete `location /` block

IMHO this is standard use case, hence I guess something small slipped my eye or I am missing out some context knowledge.

Maybe nginx has a problem with a `location` block `root` that higher than the global `root`? It serves the content though..

**What I haven't tried, yet:**

- Working with `allow` / `deny`, as it [should](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) work without

**Possible duplicate question:**

Specifically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281564/nginx-auth-basic-for-everything-except-a-specific-location) is quite similar. However it does not have the 'twist' with the different root dir and the answers haven't helped: [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281829/6919635) not working, [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22232552/6919635) seems to be quite a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to set the `auth_basic_user_file` directive within the `server` block and the `auth_basic` directive within the various `location` blocks.

I have only included the relevant configuration, for clarity. The document root and other mandatory settings are omitted on purpose.

```
server {
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/auth.txt;
    location /other {
        auth_basic off;
    }
    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
    }
}
```

Comment: But why? It should work as the docs says: "The special value off allows cancelling the effect of the auth_basic directive inherited from the previous configuration level.", see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic

Comment: @Roy - In the example above, the location `/other` is a "child" path of `/`, so that in order to disable it, one would have to specify `auth_basic off`, because the "parent" path `/`has it enabled. As per the docs, "The special value off allows cancelling the effect of the auth_basic directive inherited from the previous configuration level. ". The `auth_basic_user_file` directive has to be outside of both "levels" in order to apply to both of them.